# How to compare characters in String efficiently in Rust?

Tags: string, performance, rust, char

I am learning Rust coming from Python and have written a function to check if a word consists of unique characters. However it is very slow, in fact not any faster than its Python equivalent. This leads me to believe it is very inefficient Rust code, how can I improve performance?

This is my implementation, it is similar to how I would do it in Python:

```
fn word_has_unique_letters(word: &String) -> bool {
    for (i, letter_1) in word.get(..word.len()-1).expect("REASON").chars().enumerate(){
        for letter_2 in word.get(i+1..).expect("REASON").chars(){
            if letter_1 == letter_2{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the fastest python implementation? `len(x) == len(set(x))`? Start with implementing that.

Comment: This uses a double nested for-loop of O(n^2), for an O(n) task, which rings performance alarm bells.

Comment: Following the top answer from the suggested question as follows is ~6 times than the function 1 in my question:
`fn word_has_unique_letters(word: &String) -> bool {
    let mut uniq = HashSet::new();
    word.chars().all(move |x| uniq.insert(x))
}`

Comment: Nitpick: `.get().unwrap()` and `get().expect()` should be replaced by indexing.

Comment: Are you measuring Rust performance in release mode? If not, your numbers are likely _very_ skewed.